# Regression Summary giving me NAN on Adj R Squared and Prob(Fstatistic) in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels

Checking logistic regression summary and the is giving nan for Adj R Squared and Prob(Fstatistic) in Python. R SQuared is 1, and the F Statistic is 0.00.

Everything else I've checked seems normal and without errors, for example, accuracy is 90%.

Additionally, I looked at the data for y_train and X_train to make sure it's correct, and it is.
All I can think of at this moment is that I shouldn't have turned most of the independent variables into binary, while some (such as age and population) are continuous.

Here's some sample output

```
age     population     Tenure_Less_Than_1     Tenure_More_Than_5    
37        113,111             0                       1
25        98,201              1                       0
49        200,789             0                       1
```

Here's the code I used for the summary just in case it's helpful. If there's other code that would be helpful, let me know and I'll post it

```
lm_1 = sm.OLS(y_train, X_train).fit()
lm_1.summary()
```

Comment: Chances are that you have multicollinearity. It would be interesting to have the code and the data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: what's your df_resid? Looks more like perfect fit.

Comment: The first sentence says logistic regression, but then you use OLS.